# Ror app not running on CentOS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger, centos6, centos6.5

I am using CentOS 6.6 first time to deploy Rails 4 application. I have installed all necessary softwares like MySQL, Ruby, Rails, Passenger, Apache2, etc. I have tested it for index.html page inside /var/www/html/index.html and set it on Apache configuration and working perfect.

When I deployed Rails application it did run on the server but it displayed as shown in screenshot below.

[image]

Below are my Apache configuration settings which I have done so far.

/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
  LoadModule passenger_module /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-5.0.6/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
    PassengerDefaultRuby /home/user/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.1.2/ruby
    PassengerRoot /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-5.0.6
</IfModule>
```

I have created a file vhost.conf inside /etc/httpd/conf.d/

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName myipaddress
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/projectname/public_html/current/public
  <Directory /var/www/html/projectname/public_html/current/public>
     # This relaxes Apache security settings.
     AllowOverride all
     # MultiViews must be turned off.
     Options -MultiViews
     # Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
     #Require all granted
  </Directory>
```

I run the command below command

```
service httpd restart 
service httpd reload
```

Neither Rails app running in server nor showing any erros.

Any solution would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and always **check the Apache logs**.  This step is essential, but often overlooked.  If that doesn't help, I would try a few things:

Double-check [the documentation](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_installing_or_upgrading_on_red_hat_fedora_centos_or_scientificlinux) and make sure you've completely installed Passenger, and haven't skipped a step.

Start by removing the `IfModule` directive.  Since you want Passenger, you want an error message if it isn't loading.

```
LoadModule passenger_module /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-5.0.6/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerDefaultRuby /home/user/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.1.2/ruby
PassengerRoot /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-5.0.6
```

You have your IP address as your server name.  Make sure this doesn't conflict with any other configurations (other sites, or httpd.conf).  Otherwise, you may just be loading a different page / application.

Depending on how you have it set up, you may have permissions issues since you're pointing `PassengerDefaultRuby` and `PassengerRoot` to `/home/user/.rvm`.  By convention, these are usually somewhere more public like `/var/lib/gems/` and `/usr/bin/`.

Make sure you have defined a `root` path in your Rails application's `config/routes.rb`.

Make sure you've `chown -R`-ed your application path to the apache user.  This will help you with troubleshooting and security.

After you've done all that, check the logs again.  After you make a change, check the logs again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yea you were right some permission issue was there. I installed everything again as root user and worked for me.